# Xcode 6.0/6.1 Interface Builder resizes views to fit whole content when clicked on the corner grip to resize

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, xcode6, xcode6.1

I think this is an obvious bug on Xcode 6.0.1 but I'm searching for at least a workaround. In interface builder, I have an image view that is smaller in dimensions than the image that it contains. Here is my newly created, fresh nib with just an image view, the heart image is a larger PNG file than the containing image view:

[image]

So far so good. However, when I click on the any of the grips at the corners/edges of the view to resize the image view, it immediately changes to this the very moment I click on the grip:

[image]

This happens whenever I try to resize by hand (I can resize using width/height values at inspector though) and I have hard time trying to fit my design into the nib. The problem happens both on nibs and the storyboards. Does anyone know a workaround?

**UPDATE**: I've updated to Xcode 6.1 but I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: I'm having the same trouble with autolayout... waiting for a solution.

Comment: Solved by updating to Xcode6.1 :)

Comment: @TaketoSano I'm on 6.1 but I'm still having the same problem. Interesting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is for autolayout-enabled views/nibs. For autoresizing mask solution, see Nicolai Nita's answer: [Xcode 6.0/6.1 Interface Builder resizes views to fit whole content when clicked on the corner grip to resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26000452/xcode-6-interface-builder-resizes-views-to-fit-whole-content-when-clicked-on-the/26121840#26121840)

I've solved the problem by setting the content compression resistance priority (both vertical and horizontal) to 250 from 750. I don't know why it wasn't the case before Xcode 5 though.

Answer (score 3):

The same result I've noticed when close and reopen the project. The view continues to grow up every time. I have created a simple project to search the cause of the wrong behavior of the autoresizing mask (flexible width AND align to right).

So, try to disable "flexible width/height" and "align to right". Keep the "align to left" only.

Comment: unfortunatelly, I'm on autolayout so autoresizing mask doesn't apply in my case.